# How to calculate the area that a chip occupies in a design system

Tags: integrated-circuit, microchip

Can someone help me to find how I can calculate the area that a chip occupies in the design system of the ADS(Advanced design system) software? It is possible in this design program?

Comment: not that familiar with ADS, but what is stopping you from just measuring the width and height and multiplying the two?

Comment: Your question is weird. Do you mean how much **diskspace** a design takes in the design software or do you mean how much **physical space** your circuit will take when fabricated on a **silicon die** ? Assuming the latter: 1) You design your circuit 2) you draw a **layout** of that circuit including bondpads etc. 3) in the layout tool you measure the size of your layout.  So what is crucial: without the **layout** it is impossible to say what the size will be.

Comment: Mr Joren Vaes Ican multiplying width and height if the schematic was square.Thanks mr  Bimpelrekkie

Comment: How useful would measuring the size of the schematic be ? Are large capacitors also drawn larger in a schematic than small ones ? You can also multiply width and height to get area for rectangular (non-square) shapes. If you did not know that then you should not be using ADS.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming analog circuits, take the gate area and scale up by 5X.

Add in the resistor area scaled up by 5X (precision resistors needs lots of same-doping surround-regions, to sustain matching)

Add in the capacitor area, scaled up by 1x (that is, one-for-one).

Add in rails, sized to handle the current.

Add in 10,000 square microns per bond pad. Yes, yours may be smaller than 100U^2, but wide metal needs routing area. And where are your ESD structures?

This is for 2 or 3 layer metal. With more layers, some of the scale-up can be eased, but then you have all sorts of interferers atop the sensitive components, and you'll have to back off the coupling distances in Rev2 and Rev3.